# In Github, how can you tell if a directory has been removed?

Tags: git, github

Given a directory `/fruits` with files `apple.js, banana.js and orange.js` is there an indicator to distinguish between these two pull requests

1. Directory `/fruits` has files `apple.js, banana.js and orange.js` removed
2. Directory `/fruits` is deleted along with `apple.js, banana.js orange.js`
3. file files `apple.js, banana.js, and orange.js` have their content completely wiped but the file remains (empty file)

I'm currently looking at a PR where the directory was was removed along with its contents but in my experience it looks identical to a PR where the files contents would have been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Git, you cannot commit empty folders, because Git does not actually save folders, only files. Therefore removing all files in a directory will effectively "delete" it from your repository. This means that your examples 1. and 2. are identical.

Example 3. will be different: a file with only its contents deleted will show you a diff of all deleted lines, but a deleted file would show you a message: "This file was deleted", it looks like this:

[image: Message "This file was deleted"]